# How do I hide list columns in a view

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering, list-view-web-part

I have 3 list webparts on my home page. I've used this script to hide 2 columns on page load and changes (sorting, filtering).

```
// Override list views to hide language columns based on locale
listOverride: {
    set: function () {
        var overrideCurrentContext = {};
        overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};


        overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = listOverride.hideLanguageColumns;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
    },
    hideLanguageColumns: function () {
        // Loop through columns which need to be hidden and hide from view
        cca.locale.hiddenLangColumns.map(function (column) {
            // Get column position
            var columnIndex = $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('" + column + "')").first().index() + 1;
            // Find and Hide column
            $('th:nth-child(' + columnIndex + '),td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').hide();
        })
        console.log("list post render done")
    }
},
```

I'm experiencing two problems:

1. The CSR do not do anything on page load. I need to call listOverride.hideLanguageColumns explicitly on page load for it to take effect.
2. When I upload documents through drag n drop, the row Cells for the columns I've hidden are displayed again for the new item, but the columns are still hidden so I've got a table now with less columns then row cells.

I'm a bit stuck on both issues.

Comment: If you don't want some columns in the view, then you could just change the view in SharePoint & hide those columns using modify view button. Then add that view as webpart (sorry if i am wrong).

Comment: @Batman Why do you want to hide columns dynamically as there is a way to create views OOTB in SharePoint?Do you want to hide columns in all 3 views?

Comment: I want to hide the columns in all three webpart views. I need to manage the columns shown on the page dynamically based on various conditions. So the modify view isn't helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You are missing half the boilerplate CSR code,

**always** use [the Chrome Browser & the Cisar Extension](https://365csi.nl/cisar) to WYSIWYG edit CSR code

**2.** Your CSR does **not** execute for the new Row

Rethink how to solve this. You are now trying to update the UI with JavaScript, which is a fine approach if you have to do one update.

CSS is the Browser technology that always updates the UI

So instead of deleting/hiding the columns with JavaScript

Use CSS to hide TDs and THs with CSS

You can add <STYLE> tags with JavaScript

Comment: Hi Danny, I don't see what I'm missing, it executes on sorting/filtering so I'm not sure why it would't on page load or what I could add that would make it do that. Thanks for the extension, I'll check it out. 

2. It doesn't execute on new Row, but I couldn't find examples or documentation on an event I could register on new row so I thought OnPostRender would take care of that.

Comment: 1) Then you are not comparing your code with a correct CSR Template that also deals with the MDS feature (note that most blogs are incomplete, Cisar gives you the correct boilerplate. 2) That is why I suggest to do it with CSS, as that is **automatically** applied to all new HTML being added to a page.. yes you can program that behavior with JS.. but why write 10 lines of code if the Browser does it for you?

Comment: 1) I see, but I don't have an MDS issue, it's disabled and the code runs on sorting/filtering. That's why I'm a little confused as to why that could be the issue.

2) I don't see how adding CSS compared to calling `.hide()` would be different here. Are you saying instead of doing `.hide()` replace it with `.addClass("ms-hide")`?

Comment: I don't see how what I'm doing is different than what's in this sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-2625e5e3

Comment: I said: **Most blogs are incorrect**. So is that code posted on MSDN.. it is incomplete to work with the MDS feature. The Cisar extension gives you the correct boilerplate code

Comment: Okay I'm working with the Cisar Extension, I'll see if I can figure it out. But I don't understand the CSS remark

Answer (score 0):

Well, this got bumped to the top by Community, so I guess I'll throw my two cents in here...

Now, this is completely untested, but since I have found that you can [add fake columns that aren't actually present in the list to a view by altering the `ctx.ListSchema.Field` collection in `onPreRender`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/230312/8992), I'm guessing that the reverse might be possible - in the `onPreRender` stage, find the column you want to hide in the `ctx.ListSchema.Field` collection, and just splice it out.

Then the CSR engine won't render it, because it won't know about it.