# Can JSLink be used to add a new column in the list view?

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, custom-list, jslink

I have been studying JSLink and its possible uses and have implemented some examples. But all of the examples work by modifying value in the existing column in a list view.

Can we use JSLink to add a dummy column in the list view which acts on information of the current item? And it does not require creating column in list, say adding a button at the end of the row in list view.

Comment: yes, that should be possible by modifying the DOM onpostrender.

Comment: @Colbs: Can you please share an example?

Comment: answer posted below

Comment: I would need to load column names from another list.
So my list "ColumnNames" contains for example 10 records, each describing the name of the column to add in "onPreRender". However, I can't use ctx it seems to do a Caml Query to get those records.
I can do it the normal way, using `var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` but then I first need to load sp.js (via executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded), otherwise SP.ClientContext.get_current() is undefined. The issue is, if I delay (via executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded), it seems i'm "too late" in the sequence to still be able to add columns in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can add a dummy field not present on the list by adding to the `ctx.ListSchema.Field` collection in `OnPreRender`.  Then, when the actual rendering starts, SharePoint will just add another column on the view automatically.  Then you can add something into that cell in `OnPostRender`.

Here's an example of the code to add the field definition into the schema to make the dummy column:

```
function addTemporaryField(ctx) {
    // make sure we haven't added the field already,
    // in case OnPreRender fires twice, which it does sometimes
    if (ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (fld) {
        return fld.Name == 'FakeField';
    }).length == 0) {

        // create the field schema object to insert
        var FakeFieldObj = {
            AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
            DisplayName: 'Fake Field',
            RealFieldName: 'FakeField',
            Name: 'FakeField',
            FieldType: 'Text',
            Type: 'Text',
            Filterable: 'FALSE',
            Sortable: 'FALSE',
            ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
        };

        // find the index of the field to insert next to,
        // based on that field's DISPLAY name.
        var insertIdx = ctx.ListSchema.Field.map(function (fld) {
            return fld.DisplayName;
        }).indexOf('Some Field Name');

        // if you want to insert *before* the field do not add anything
        // but, if you want to insert *after* the field, add 1
        insertIdx++;

        // insert your fake field schema object into the list schema
        ctx.ListSchema.Field.splice(insertIdx, 0, FakeFieldObj);
    }
}
```

I wrote [a blog post about it](https://morefunthanapokeintheeye.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-add-temporary-columns-to-list-views.html) where I also go into inserting data into the dummy column, and you could certainly render a button in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code I wrote for your situation. I was initially thinking about adding an actual `<td>` element to the `<table>`, however, manipulating an existing field is much easier than the DOM.

You need to first add a new placeholder field in your list. That is where the button will be rendered. You basically override the item render and return the proper html with the button.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [];

    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields =
    {
        'Button': { 'View': renderButton }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function renderButton(ctx){ 
    var btnTxt = ctx.CurrentItem["Button"];
    var id = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;

    return "<input type='button' onclick='btnClick(" + id + ")' value='" + 
    btnTxt + "'></input>";

}

function btnClick(id) {
  alert("button " + id + " clicked");
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Michael that worked, is there a quick way to check status or a column value for the row? The other options i could think of is to open the form in a new tab or write rest apis to change values

Comment: var status = ctx.CurrentItem["Status"];

Comment: Sorry, I mean update the value of the column! I definitely got the value using the above solutions